# I keep getting http 403 error for Google Oauth 2.0 (Titanium Alloy)

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am creating an iphone application and trying to get the user information once i login using the google, but i keep getting 403 error. I am using the google Oauth API, whiche i found [here](http://blog.ejci.net/2012/07/14/google-oauth-2-0-for-titanium/). Am i doing something wrong here ? Following is the flow and code. Not to mention I am using Titanium.

1) User opens app logs in using google.

2) Once authentication is successful, user is taken to a home view where he gets to see his profile.(More things are there but going one at a time)

I have already enabled the API on google and generated keys and all. Am I missing something or doing a step wrong ?

```
var GoogleAuth = Alloy.Globals.GoogleAuth;
var googleAuth = new GoogleAuth({
    clientId : 'clientxxxxxxid',
    clientSecret : 'secret',
    propertyName : 'profile',
    scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','email']
});

function loginWithGoogle(){
    googleAuth.isAuthorized(
    function(){
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

            onerror: function(d){Ti.API.error(d);},
            timeout:5000
        });
        //alert(googleAuth.getAccessToken());
        var accessToken =  googleAuth.getAccessToken();
        client.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken);
        client.open('GET','https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=_API_KEY_');
        client.send();
        client.onload = function(d){
            alert(d);
        };
        //https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
    },
    function(){
    googleAuth.authorize(function(){
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

            onerror: function(d){
                Ti.API.error(d);
            },
            timeout:5000
        });
        //alert(googleAuth.getAccessToken());
        var accessToken = googleAuth.getAccessToken();
        client.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+accessToken);
        client.open('GET','https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=_API_KEY_');
        client.send();
        client.onload = function(d){
            alert(d);
        };
        //https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
    }); 
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code...

This:

```
client.open('GET','https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=_API_KEY_');
```

should be like this:

```
client.open('GET','https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=' + googleAuth.getAccessToken());
```

Comment: i corrected the code as u suggested now m getting  {"type":"load","source":{"cache":false},"code":0,"success":true} as a response.

Comment: I am expecting a user-profile response where i can get get his email,photo, first and las last name etc.

Comment: Please read this documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp. You need to set scope to right values... scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login','profile'] (similar to that)